# How to split a long string in 2 strings by words, but not in the middle of a word[java]

Tags: string, stringtokenizer

If my string is too long, I want to split it in 2 substrings and show it.

This is the code I use:

```
if(newQuestion.length() > 35){
            String first_part = newQuestion.substring(0,newQuestion.length()/2);
            String second_part = newQuestion.substring(newQuestion.length()/2);
            question1.setText(first_part + "\n" + second_part);
        }
        else{question1.setText(newQuestion + "");}
```

Which results in:

> Bronze age settlemen
>
> ts in northern India.

How do I split it if the total string length is > 35, but not split the actual word, since it is not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on space. Then add words to the first string until the string is 35 chars long, then add the rest of the words to the 2. string. But it sounds like the view `question1` should be able to handle this itself?

```
    String newQuestion = "Bronze age settlements in northern India.";
    String[] words = newQuestion.split(" ");
    String line1 = "";
    String line2 = "";
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; (line1.length() + words[i].length()) < 25; i++) {
        size++;
        line1 += words[i] + " ";
    }
    for(int j = size; j < words.length; j++) {
         line2 += words[j] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(line1);
    System.out.println(line2);
```

Comment: no, the view just shows the entire long string in one line

Comment: "split on space" - does it mean use tokenizer? will you give some code?

Comment: this is such a great piece of code, very smart condition in the first loop.... thanks!